# How to Manipulate Output based on ListView Item Source Property

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I am setting `ListView ItemSource` to a `List<T>` where `T` is my Model. I am Binding some of the Property of this `List<T>` to some Label in XAML. And Now based on a Property, I want to Set Label to some Text.

For Example, `if  (Property.IsCompleted == true)`, I might want to set a Label in my View Cell in the `ListView` to "Done" instead of "True".

I hope this summarizes the problem. I have tried other things and none worked.

This is the Item Appearing Method of My ListView:

```
          private void bookingLV_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
        {
            BookingsModel convert = (BookingsModel)e.Item;
            var select = convert.IsCompleted;
         if(select == true)
            {
                IsDone = "Completed";
            }
            IsDone = "Pending";

        }
```

And I have a Custom Property called IsDone:

```
  public string IsDone { get; set; }
```

And This is how I am Binding IsDone in the View Cell of the ListView in Xaml

```
 <Label Text="{Binding IsDone}"></Label>
```

I want to be able to set the Text Property of my Label to some text based on a property of my Model Object.

Comment: either 1)  use a ValueConverter, or 2) use a custom property on your model that returns the text

Comment: @Jason I did the number two as you can see from my question. You mind explaining this to me explicitly with an example?

Comment: IsDone does not appear to be a property of BookingsModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a read only property in your model that returns a value based on another property

```
public string IsDone 
{ 
  get
    {
       if (select) return "Completed";
       return "Pending";
    }
}
```

if you are using `INotifyPropertyChanged` you will want to be sure that the setter of the "trigger" property fires `PropertyChanged` events for both

```
public bool selected { 
  get {
    ...
  }
  set {
    ...
    PropertyChanged("selected");
    PropertyChanged("IsDone");
  }
}
```